# Need help to display custom message in Magento Shipping Module

Tags: magento-1.9

I am creating shipping module. Which is working fine. But in addition I want to show custom message with each shipping method I have used.

For example In this below code I have used `$rate->setMethodTitle('Standard delivery');` to set title of the method, with this method I want to display a description too. Please guide how I can define a description of this method.

```
$rate = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');
$rate->setCarrier($this->_code);
$rate->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));
$rate->setMethod('large');
$rate->setMethodTitle('Standard delivery');
$rate->setPrice($price);
$rate->setCost(0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an extension that does what you want:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/multi-flat-shipping-1.html

Check out the screen shots.

I am sure you can copy the 'info text' from that module into your own. Enjoy.